# draggable div should be avoid x and y overlap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I have a problem with draggable element which overlapping screen area. Here is example of code:

```
onDrag(pageX: number, pageY: number) {
    if (this.isDragging) {
      const deltaX = pageX - this.lastPageX;
      const deltaY = pageY - this.lastPageY;

      const coords = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.element.nativeElement.style.left = `${coords.left + deltaX}px`;
      this.element.nativeElement.style.top = `${coords.top + deltaY}px`;

      this.lastPageX = pageX;
      this.lastPageY = pageY;
   }
}
```

What i exactly want is when `element` reaches of screen it should be style `left: 0;` or etc.

[image]

Here is a [stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ks6i5). What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add these lines to your `onDrag` function:

```
  if(coords.left + deltaX > 0 && coords.right + deltaX < window.innerWidth) {
    this.element.nativeElement.style.left = `${coords.left + deltaX}px`;
  }

  if (coords.top + deltaY > 0 && coords.bottom + deltaY < window.innerHeight) {
    this.element.nativeElement.style.top = `${coords.top + deltaY}px`;
  }
```